# Run a javascript function on focus out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript function:

```
    function testCreditCard () {
    myCardNo = document.getElementById('ccnumber').value;
    myCardType = document.getElementById('ccType').value;
    if (checkCreditCard (myCardNo,myCardType)) {
        alert ("Credit card has a valid format")
    } 
    else {
        alert (ccErrors[ccErrorNo])
        };
    }
```

and an input field `<input type="text" id="ccnumber" />`

and the script function is triggered using an onclick function

```
<button type="post" id="btn_c" name="btn_c" onclick="testCreditCard();" >Click</button>
```

Is there anyway I could trigger the function on focus out/right after filling the input field?

Im new to javascript / jquery.Please suggest a solution for this.Thank You

Tried this

```
<input type="text" id="ccnumber" />
<script> //Script for testCreditCard </script>
    <script>$("#ccnumber").on("change", testCreditCard);</script>
    <script>
    function testCreditCard () {
      myCardNo = document.getElementById('ccnumber').value;
      myCardType = document.getElementById('ccType').value;
      if (checkCreditCard (myCardNo,myCardType)) {
      } 
      else {alert (ccErrors[ccErrorNo])};
    }
    </script>

</body>
```

But didnt work.

Comment: Sounds like you're really looking for the change event ?

Comment: the blur event will fire when an element loses focus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why you don't try to call onblur property of the input text?

```
    <input type="text" onblur="testCreditCard()" id="id" name="id" />
```

when the focus is out of the text the js function is activated

my apologies for my english

Answer (score 5):

Bind to the `change` or `blur` event

```
$("#ccnumber").on("change", testCreditCard);
```

Comment: Can u please cehck my question,updated,i tried this,but doesnt seem to work.Please help

Comment: What does not work? what is the error in the console? You do not have to wrap each thing in a script block.

Comment: @CSharper That is WRONG

Comment: In the console,no errors are there.But the alert is not coming.I will create a fiddle and update.

Comment: Are you actually using jQuery? Did you actually change the value for the event to fire? If not, you need to use `blur`...

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
 <input type="text" id="ccnumber" onblur ="testCreditCard()" />
```

or try

```
$"#ccnumber").on("blur", function(){
          testCreditCard();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different binding than the already posted answers, but same idea.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(document).on("blur", "#ccnumber", function() {
       testCreditCard(); 
});

function testCreditCard () {
      myCardNo = document.getElementById('ccnumber').value;
      myCardType = document.getElementById('ccType').value;
      if (checkCreditCard (myCardNo,myCardType)) {
      } 
      else {alert (ccErrors[ccErrorNo])};
}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9Gphp/